# $f(4)=3$ and $f'(4)=7$. If $g(x)=x^2f(x)$ then find $g'(4)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $f(4)=3$ and $f'(4)=7$. If  $g(x)=x^2f(x)$ then find $g'(4)$.

I'm a little confused on this problem. If anybody can help me with this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you mean to say that $f(4) = 3$ _not_ $f\,\,'(4) = 3$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, I should have seen my typing error sooner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: The product rule states that $$g'(x) = x^2 f'(x) + 2x f(x)$$

Now use the given information when $x = 4$.

---

Note that I am assuming there's a typo in your original post, since $3 \ne 7$.

Comment: @JohnBeal The equation I gave *is* for $g'(x)$. I'm not sure what you mean.